# How to form a dataframe in R using lists

Tags: r

I have child_sequences as `list` in R

```
child = c("a","b","c")
```

I generate this child sequence over and over again based on some logic using a `for` loop, let say -

```
child1 = c("a","b","c")
child2 = c("b","a","c")
child3 = c("a","a","b")
```

and so on.

I want all this lists to be stored as a dataframe so that I can save it to csv and analyze it later.

How do I do it efficiently in R? How can I keep appending this list to dataframe using the same `for` loop?

My dataframe should look like -

```
a , b ,c 
b, a, c
a, a, b
```

Comment: Those aren't lists you have. Those are vectors. Lists and vectors are different things in R.

Comment: how do i check if a variable type is list or vector ?

Comment: You can use `is.list()` to see if something is a list. But building a data.frame row-by-row in R is one of the most inefficient things you can do in R. It's much better to build the data frame column-by-column. What's the actual scenario you are dealing with.

Comment: thank you for the help. I am trying to create a data frame from lists. I can convert vector to list in each for loop call. But at the end I am trying to create a dataframe from this list.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
child1 = c("a","b","c")
child2 = c("b","a","c")
child3 = c("a","a","b")

child_list <- list(child1, child2, child3)

as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, child_list))
```

> ```
>   V1 V2 V3
> 1  a  b  c
> 2  b  a  c
> 3  a  a  b
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many objects of the same pattern name, we can use `ls` (specify the `pattern` and with `mget` return the object values in a `list`.  Here, is another option with `bind_rows` (from `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(mget(ls(pattern = "^child\\d+$")))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  child1 child2 child3
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 a      b      a     
#2 b      a      a     
#3 c      c      b
```